# Is Red based on some real bird species?

Tags: character, angry-birds

In the 2016 released and game-based 3D animation movie "Angry Birds" we all know the main character is Red. Is this character based on a real living bird or just an imagination?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's based on [Northern cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_cardinal)

[image]

Even claimed same on [angrybirds wikia](http://angrybirds.wikia.com/wiki/Red)

> Red Bird is the main protagonist in the Angry Birds series and games
> created by Rovio Entertainment. He is the first bird to play with. He
> is also the leader of the Flock. First introduced in 2009, the
> character is the primary bird used in marketing to promote the series.
> Red is a Cardinal.
>
> In the film version, Red appears as a red anthropomorphic Northern Cardinal with red feathered hands and his chest is light red instead of beige, his eyes are brown instead of black and the maroon spots in each sides of his face is now one instead of two and has orange feet

[Northern Cardinal looks just like Angry Bird in pictures below:](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3634081/Angry-s-furious-Brilliant-picture-red-Northern-Cardinal-looks-just-like-Angry-Bird-popular-mobile-game.html)

[image][image]

[audubon.org](http://www.audubon.org/news/what-kinds-birds-are) tried to identify all 5 major birds from the game with the help of  legendary birder and field guide author Kenn Kaufman. And here his findings/claims:

[image] [image]

Left one is [Blue Finch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_finch) and right one is [Northern cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_cardinal)

[image]  [image]

Left one is [Greater Antillean bullfinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Antillean_bullfinch) and right one is [Yellow Warbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_yellow_warbler)

[image]

White one is [Snow bunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_bunting)

*Still not able to find any official source, as many other bird expert claiming [different conclusion](http://www.birdchick.com/blog/2011/02/field-guide-to-angry-birds) for the rest of the birds.*

Comment: Great answer. I have a feeling the white bird isn't based on any real bird, though, so much as it is based on an egg, fitting its in-game purpose.

Comment: @ArrowCase both have yellow on there cheek